# Sorting text data into variables and rows in R

Tags: r

I have text data in a string variable that I want to arrange into TEXT, WHO and TIME variables in R.

The data is structured so it is possible to apply these rules:

1. Grep text until "PersonA |" or "PersonB |" and add to TEXT variable
2. Add PersonA/PersonB to WHO variable
3. Add date to TIME variable

```
example_data <- "how are you? what, are u thinking about. anything! PersonA | 2020-03-20 3:49\nI'm fine thanks PersonB | 2020-03-20 3:49\nWhat are you doing? PersonA | 2020-03-20 3:50\nPlaying card PersonB | 2020-03-20 3:49\n"
```

The data is structured so it is possible to apply these rules:

1. Grep text until "PersonA |" or "PersonB |" and add to TEXT variable
2. Add PersonA/PersonB to WHO variable
3. Add date to TIME variable

```
# Desired output
TEXT <- c("how are you?", "I'm fine thanks", "What are you doing?", "Playing card")
WHO <- c("PersonA", "PersonB", "PersonA", "PersonB")
TIME <- c("2020-03-20 3:49", "2020-03-20 3:49", "2020-03-20 3:50", "2020-03-20 3:49")

output <- data.frame(TEXT, WHO, TIME)
output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to replace the delimiters with a single delimiter (`;`) and then read with `read.csv` from `base R`

```
read.csv(text = gsub("\\s(?=Person)|\\s+\\|\\s+", ";", example_data, 
   perl = TRUE), sep = ";", header = FALSE, col.names = c("TEXT", "WHO", "TIME"))
```

-output

```
                                                TEXT     WHO            TIME
1 how are you? what, are u thinking about. anything! PersonA 2020-03-20 3:49
2                                    I'm fine thanks PersonB 2020-03-20 3:49
3                                What are you doing? PersonA 2020-03-20 3:50
4                                       Playing card PersonB 2020-03-20 3:49
```

Comment: thanks, but i've noticed that this does not work with more complex text data (which is why I was proposing some rules :) ? Ive updated the example with more complex text data.

Comment: @John I updated by changing the delimiter as you `,` already between the text